# In react class component why is the state not being changed in the first instance of button click? But in the second instance it gets updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below code when I click the button for the first time it prints the original state values even though the state is changed using setState(). But when I click the button for the second time it prints the new state values

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component{
  state = {
    name:'Aneesh',
    age: '30'
  }

  handleClick= (event)=>{
    //this prints the original state
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
      name:'Rayancha'
    })
    //This prints the original state in the first click and prints the new state after the second click
    console.log(this.state);
  }




  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>I am app component</h1>
        <p>My name is: {this.state.name} and my Age is {this.state.age}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `setState` is an asynchronous function as detailed in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: Thanks for the accept algoboy :)! Hope my solution was useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually is updating correctly. The problem is executing `console.log(this.state)` directly after calling `this.setState()`. You see, `this.setState()` is asynchronous, which means when you call it, there's nothing to stop code that is written after it from running immediately. Simply put, `console.log()` runs before state has finished updating.

As proof that your state actually updated, you can run a `console.log()` inside `render`. Since, a component will `re-render` every time you update state, you will be printing the new state value.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component{
  state = {
    name:'Aneesh',
    age: '30'
  }

  handleClick= (event)=>{
    //this prints the original state
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
      name:'Rayancha'
    })
    //This prints the original state in the first click and prints the new state after the second click
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.name)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>I am app component</h1>
        <p>My name is: {this.state.name} and my Age is {this.state.age}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

`setState` works in an asynchronous way. That means after calling setState the `this.state` variable is not immediately changed. So, in case you want to perform an action immediately after setting state on a state variable and then return a result, use callback.
Try using callback function as below:

```
handleClick= (event)=>{
    //this prints the original state
    console.log(this.state);
    this.setState({
      name:'Rayancha'
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }
```

This will ensure that, console.log is called when `setState` is returned.

Comment: Additionally, if you can use async/await you can mark the arrow function as `async` and `await` the `setState`. Subsequent code will only run after state has been updated.

Comment: @Phillip That is not true because `setState` doesn't return a `Promise` (you cannot `await` it).

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it correctly, console will be executed before your state is set, So if you put console in render you can see your state has changed correctly.

To fix this you have to pass a callback to the setState that will execute only after your setState is executed.

Use a callback if it is really needed, if you want to use state under render you must avoid this as in case of multiple renders it will make your application slow.

```
handleClick= (event)=>{
    this.setState({
      name:'Rayancha'
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }
```

Please go through the official docs for seState Api https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate